# Queue in main thread is empty after adding to it from worker thread

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, tkinter

I am trying to create a basic console window using tkinter. My current code has two classes, one for the gui and one for adding text to the console. The text adding class is running in a different thread than the gui (which is running in the main thread). I have a queue set up to communicate between the two threads. Everything works except for the queue. When I add text to the queue, it can be read from the worker thread but not the main thread. Here is my code:

```
import threading, sys, os, time, Queue
from Tkinter import *

class consolegui:
    """Main GUI for the program"""
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root=root
        self.cout=Text(self.root, width=80)
        self.root.after(100, self.process_queue)
        self.cout.config(state=DISABLED)
        self.cout.pack(side=TOP)
        self.bottomf=Frame(self.root, height=1, width=80)
        self.bottomf.pack(side=BOTTOM)
        self.cin=Entry(self.bottomf, width=100)
        self.cin.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.enter=Button(self.bottomf, text="send", command=self.on_click)
        self.cin.bind('<Return>', self.on_click)
        self.enter.pack(side=BOTTOM)
        self.queue = Queue.Queue()
        worker(self.queue).start()
    def on_click(self, *args):
        self.cout.config(state=NORMAL)
        self.cout.insert(END, self.cin.get()+'\n')
        self.cout.config(state=DISABLED)
        self.cin.delete(0, END)
    def add_text(self, text):
        self.cout.insert(END, text+'\n')
    def process_queue(self):
        print "reading queue"
        try:
            msg = self.queue.get(0)
            print "found items in queue!"
            self.add_text(msg)
            with self.queue.mutex:
                self.queue.queue.clear()
        except Queue.Empty:
            print "found nothing"
            self.root.after(100, self.process_queue)
class worker(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue
    def run(self):
        time.sleep(5)
        print "adding to queue"
        self.queue.put("Task finished")
        print self.queue.get(0)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    console=consolegui(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure it's not readable from the main thread? You're using a non-blocking `get`, and sleeping between checks. The worker only adds a single item to the queue, and reads it back immediately (which empties the queue). The race condition you've created would require the Python [GIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_interpreter_lock) to swap to the main thread *exactly* between the `put` and the `get` at the exact 100 second mark between checks (and as written, it looks like you're adding after five seconds so it's likely got ~95 seconds to go, and that race will never happen).

Short answer: You can only `get` an entry from a `Queue` once. If the worker reads it immediately, the main thread can't (and vice versa).